# Catalog price rules - cant add more than "category" or "attributeset"

Tags: catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules

i finally was about to add some catalog price rules. 
I´ve googled many times and cant explain it to myself so far. 
Why I just can choose between two options: category and attributeset?

I´ve seen many screenshots where they can choose from many more options. I cant realize the requirements of the shopowner this way and still beeing speechless.

I have to add discounts per manufacturer - manufacturer are given within the attributesets.

Did I do something wrong or forget something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have attributes set to be used in rules.
Go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes, edit the attributes you want to use in catalog rules and set the flag `Use for Promo Rule Conditions` to `Yes`.

Comment: That simple - that useful... Thanks very much